# ChromeOS - Save file instead of viewing in Quickoffice

Tags: google-chrome-os

When I open any link to an Office document, like .doc or .ppt, ChromeOS automatically opens the file in Quickoffice Viewer. I would like to save the file locally so that I can add it to Google Docs, but Quickoffice deletes the file as soon as the Quickoffice tab is closed. Quickoffice's Save As option only saves as mhtml. Trying to access the file while Quickoffice has it open does not work because the app changes the extension of the file to .webintents.

I have tried removing the Quickoffice Viewer extension, but Chrome just displays an error and deletes the downloaded file.

In some cases I can right click and choose Save Link As..., but in many cases the file is automatically generated by a website, so the link is to an aspx page that creates the file and not to the .ppt.

Is there a way to *not* preview an Office file that is generated dynamically, and to instead save it to the disk on ChromeOS?

Answer (score 1):

When you Save As, in the box containing the file name, simply delete ".mhtml" and it will save as .doc  (.doc is already in the filename).
I found this also works when I download files from sugarsync: it adds .webintents to the file name, which makes it very difficult to open.
Hope this helps

Comment: The provided answer doesn't work for me. When I change the Save As filename then view the .doc file, it just reads like HTML code. Downloading from Google Drive/Docs used to be flawless. I just noticed this problem today.